# Kinetic JS change focus when mouseup

Tags: kineticjs

I used for loop to generate 10 circles,

and mouseup the current circle,

```
var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
for(var i =0; i<10; i++){    
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 50+i*50,
    y: 50+i*50,
    radius: 10,
    fill: 'black',
    id: i
});
shapesLayer.add(circle);
circle.on('mouseup', function() {
    circle.setFill('black'); // this is not working
    this.setFill('red');  
    shapesLayer.draw();
    });
```

}

I want to change the focus of circle, while mouseup one circle ,the circle change to color red, but other circle change back the color to black.  anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mouseup handler, reset all circle fills to black, then set the selected circle’s fill to red:

First, add `name:"circle"` to each circle you create so you can later get them by name:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
   x: 50+i*50,
   y: 50+i*50,
   radius: 10,
   fill: 'black',
   id: i,
   name:"circle"
});
```

Then in your mouseup handler:

1. Reset each circle fill to black.
2. Set the fill of the selected circle to red.

   ```
         circle.on('mouseup', function() {
             // reset all circle fills to black
             resetToBlackOnMouseUp()
             // then set this circle's fill to red
             this.setFill('red');  
             layer.draw();
         });
   ```

This function will reset the fill of  all circles named "circle" to black.

```
      // reset all circle fills to black
      function resetToBlackOnMouseUp(){
          // get all elements named "circle"
          var circles=stage.get(".circle");
          // set their fills to black
          circles.each( function(circle){
              circle.setFill("black");
          });
      }
```

If you will only have 1 set of circles on your stage you have an alternate & more efficient option.

You could save a reference to the previously red circle and then reset just that fill to black.

```
var redCircle;

// add mouseup handler
circle.on('mouseup', function() {
    // reset the previous red circle's fill to black
    redCircle.setFill("black");
    // then set this circle's fill to red
    this.setFill('red');  
    // now this circle becomes the red circle
    redCircle=this;

    layer.draw();
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CyxSj/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #buttons {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 10px;
      }
      #buttons > input {
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.3.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">

      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      for(var i =0; i<10; i++){    
          var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
              x: 50+i*50,
              y: 50+i*50,
              radius: 10,
              fill: 'black',
              id: i,
              name:"circle"
          });
          // add mouseup handler
          circle.on('mouseup', function() {
              // reset all circle fills to black
              resetToBlackOnMouseUp()
              // then set this circle's fill to red
              this.setFill('red');  
              layer.draw();
          });
          layer.add(circle);
          console.log(i);
      }
      layer.draw();

      // reset all circle fills to black
      function resetToBlackOnMouseUp(){
          // get all elements named "circle"
          var circles=stage.get(".circle");
          // set their fills to black
          circles.each( function(circle){
              circle.setFill("black");
          });
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didnt do we can assign the name and get it from the name assigned.